# Как убрать пробелы в значениях Data frame python

Tags: python, парсер, pandas, dataframe

Написал программу по парсингу таблицы с отчетностью (форма 101 с сайта ЦБ):

```
import pandas as pd
url = 'http://cbr.ru/credit/101.asp?regnum=1000&when=0&dt=20170901'
df = pd.read_html(url, header=1)[1]

# Все строки ниже - просто называю столбцы и удаляю ненужные данные
df = df.rename(columns={
        'по дебету': 'Счет', 'по кредиту': 'Сальдо ВХ 1', 
        'Unnamed: 2': 'Сальдо ВХ 2', 'Unnamed: 3': 'Сальдо ВХ',
        'Unnamed: 4': 'ДО 1', 'Unnamed: 5': 'ДО 2',
        'Unnamed: 6': 'ДО', 'Unnamed: 7': 'КО 1',
        'Unnamed: 8': 'КО 2', 'Unnamed: 9': 'КО',
        'Unnamed: 10': 'Сальдо ВЫХ 1', 'Unnamed: 11': 'Сальдо ВЫХ 2',
        'Unnamed: 12': 'Сальдо ВЫХ',
        })

df.drop(['Сальдо ВХ 1'], axis=1, inplace=True)
df.drop(['Сальдо ВХ 2'], axis=1, inplace=True)
df.drop(['ДО 1'], axis=1, inplace=True)
df.drop(['ДО 2'], axis=1, inplace=True)
df.drop(['КО 1'], axis=1, inplace=True)
df.drop(['КО 2'], axis=1, inplace=True)
df.drop(['Сальдо ВЫХ 1'], axis=1, inplace=True)
df.drop(['Сальдо ВЫХ 2'], axis=1, inplace=True)
df.drop(0, axis=0, inplace=True)
df.drop(1, axis=0, inplace=True)
df.drop(2, axis=0, inplace=True)
df.drop(3, axis=0, inplace=True)
```

Свою задачу она выполняет - выгружает таблицу, НО данные так спарсились, что между разрядами цифр остаются пробелы, следовательно я не могу производить никаких дальнейших вычислений.

Чего я только не делал:

```
for i in df['Сальдо ВХ']: #df['Сальдо ВХ'] - это один из столбцов датафрейма
    str(i).split()
    str(i).replace(' ', '')
    print(i)
```

Пробелы не удаляются! Есть идеи как это вылечить?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Попробуйте так:

```
url = 'http://cbr.ru/credit/101.asp?regnum=1000&when=0&dt=20170901'
df = pd.read_html(url, header=1)[1]

# Все строки ниже - просто называю столбцы и удаляю ненужные данные
df = df.rename(columns={
        'по дебету': 'Счет', 'по кредиту': 'Сальдо ВХ 1', 
        'Unnamed: 2': 'Сальдо ВХ 2', 'Unnamed: 3': 'Сальдо ВХ',
        'Unnamed: 4': 'ДО 1', 'Unnamed: 5': 'ДО 2',
        'Unnamed: 6': 'ДО', 'Unnamed: 7': 'КО 1',
        'Unnamed: 8': 'КО 2', 'Unnamed: 9': 'КО',
        'Unnamed: 10': 'Сальдо ВЫХ 1', 'Unnamed: 11': 'Сальдо ВЫХ 2',
        'Unnamed: 12': 'Сальдо ВЫХ',
        })

cols2drop = ['Сальдо ВХ 1','Сальдо ВХ 2','ДО 1','ДО 2','КО 1','КО 2','Сальдо ВЫХ 1','Сальдо ВЫХ 2']

df = df.iloc[4:].drop(cols2drop,axis=1)

# удалить пробелы
df = df.replace(r'\s+','',regex=True)

# удалить строки, в которых в столбце `Счет` "нечисловая" строка
# например: (`Итого...`,`Пассив`,`Актив`, etc.)
df = df[pd.to_numeric(df['Счет'], errors='coerce').notnull()]

# преобразовываем строки в числа для всех столбцов кроме `Счет`
df[df.columns.drop('Счет')] = df[df.columns.drop('Счет')].apply(pd.to_numeric, errors='coerce')
```

Проверка:

```
In [286]: df.dtypes
     ...:
Out[286]:
Счет          object
Сальдо ВХ      int64
ДО             int64
КО             int64
Сальдо ВЫХ     int64
dtype: object

In [287]: df.sum()
Out[287]:
Счет          1060510610202022020820209203022030320305203082...
Сальдо ВХ                                          148399112236
ДО                                                 249968918942
КО                                                 249968918942
Сальдо ВЫХ                                         148720260088
dtype: object

In [288]: df
Out[288]:
      Счет   Сальдо ВХ           ДО           КО  Сальдо ВЫХ
4    10605    17718607      1673543      2117638    17274512
5    10610     5693942        11612       712636     4992918
6    20202    23395759    231736538    232812087    22320210
7    20208     7092439     39166028     39072777     7185690
8    20209      292437    179148992    179217098      224331
9    20302    95028043     51591666     33806199   112813510
10   20303     4308590      2871870      2739702     4440758
..     ...         ...          ...          ...         ...
638  96901   454924157   8189147242   7974050346   239827261
639  96902   236707122   4135908603   4151928406   252726925
640  97001      232919      7874251      7641332           0
641  97002    12360424    287850457    281805495     6315462
642  97101       16054      8568133     12395552     3843473
643  97102      373316      7781036      7966640      558920
644  99997  5080588341  17827825624  17763424735  5016187452

[629 rows x 5 columns]
```